# Giving React state a name in DevTools

Tags: reactjs, state

When using React useState(), if you have something like the following `const [cartItems, setCartItems] = useState([])` it shows in React DevTools as `State: []`. Other than changing the state from an array into an object containing an array such as `useState({ cartItems: [] })` is there anything else I can do to show a key for the state? If not, is this bad practice to use an object or am I ok using this? Reason I want to have a key, is when debugging if you have a number of different items of state, the DevTools just shows as `State: [], State: {[...]}, State: []` etc which is difficult to see what is what.

Comment: Don't think you can.

Answer (score 1):

Not really since the `useState` hook uses array destructuring to assign variable names, i.e. the names are *only* used within the function, not in the react framework.

```
const [someSpecialAwesomestate, setSomeSpecialAwesomestate] = useState();
```

equates to

```
const stateObject = useState();
// stateObject[0] is the state
// stateObject[1] is the callback state mutator function
```

From what I understand, React further obfuscates this by simply storing the hooks themselves internally in an array.

It may be a bit more verbose to store objects with a single root key, and tedious to manage state updates, but if it helps your dev flow to see what each state object ***IS*** in the devtool, then *why not* do what helps you code better?